# Netsuite: OAuth1 / Token-Based Authentication where to put the state parameter

Tags: python, oauth, netsuite

I want to connect to Netsuite via Token-Based Authentication (i.e. OAuth1) as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_156347873375.html).

In the section [Step One Obtain An Unauthorized Request Token](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_156338994830.html) it is written that an optional state parameter can be added to the Authorization Header. There they also refer to [RFC 6749, Section 4.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) for further information. However, what is explained there has nothing to do with OAuth1.0 but Oauth2.0.

The reason why I depend on the state parameter is that I have the url to which the callback server shall forward the request after the authorization is done encoded in it (using JWT).

Now when I create the OAuth1 authorization header with oauthlib using the sign method from oauthlib.oauth1.Client in Python

```
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_HMAC_SHA256
from oauthlib.oauth1 import Client    
client = Client(client_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                callback_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
                signature_method=SIGNATURE_HMAC_SHA256)
uri, headers, body = client.sign(uri="https://123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken", http_method='POST')
```

I get this for headers:

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="123..", oauth_timestamp="163...", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_consumer_key="f18...", oauth_callback="...", oauth_signature="9kae..."'
}
```

I can acquire the temporary credentials when sending the request with this headers to https://123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken.

Still as I need the state parameter later on on my side I somehow need to add the state parameter to the authorization header (at least that is what Netsuite says in their documentation).
When I add my state parameter to the authorization header (the one created before by the sign method from oauthlib.oauth1.Client) like this

```
from oauthlib.common import to_unicode
headers["Authorization"] = f'{headers["Authorization"]}, state="{to_unicode(data=state, encoding="UTF-8")}"'
```

which results in this for headers (I will refer to it as new_headers):

```
# headers with state appended to Authorization
headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="123...", oauth_timestamp="163...", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_consumer_key="f18...", oauth_callback="...", oauth_signature="9kae...", state="eyJ0..."'}
```

I get this response when trying to send a request to the request token url with this header:

```
{"error" : {"code" : "USER_ERROR", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}
```

When I do it differently (not as specified in the doc) and add the state parameter to the request token url like this "https://123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken?state=eyJ0..." and send the previous header with authorization not including the state (i.e. headers) I again get to the login page. So I can assume this could work.

My problem is that I cannot test it at the moment with a Netsuite account so I just need to implement it according to the documentation and hope that I send the state parameter in the right way and it is forwarded to the callback server after a user logs in.

Now my question is:

**Is the documentation correct and the state parameter needs to be added to the authorization header like in "new_headers" above and I just do sth wrong here. If so what am I doing wrong here?**

**Or is the documentation misleading as simply adding the state parameter as a normal query parameter to the request token url like this *"https://123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/requesttoken?state=eyJ0..."* is correct?**

I would really appreciate some help here!

Best regards,
JayKay